# Unable to access backend after attempting database backup

Tags: magento-1.8, error, backend

After initiating a backup procedure to back-up our database, the back-end became unresponsive yet the front end does still work. When I reset my browser cookies, thus destroying my session, logging in gives me the following:

[image]

Now, clicking the error log hyperlink really redirects me to a page which, in turn, shows me the same except it brings me a new log ID. Clicking that redirects me to a new log ID, etc etc.

I'm not really sure on what to do now. The front end is perfectly accessible yet the back end fails on me. We are using Magento 1.8.1.0.

Comment: access your server, then look for a file under var/report/303765278316

Comment: @JulienLachal that log shows: `a:5:{i:0;s:91:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction";i:1;s:3552:"#0 `... I have the feeling the backup caused the SQL server to hang.

Comment: You've probably got a pending SQL query that's preventing you from going on. Restart your SQL process

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how your initiated the backup (either via the Magento admin, or via command line) - you will cause varying effects on your store.

The inbuilt Magento backup utility should not be used on a production store, heck, it shouldn't be used on a development store - it isn't good.

When you trigger a backup, it needs exclusive locks on tables/rows so that when it takes a copy of the data from that point in time - it is consistent, which means every other process that tries to manipulate the DB (updates/inserts) will be forced to queue until the backup process is complete. The effects of starting a backup, when other processes are taking place can cause a catastrophic chain of events, causing a series of queries to queue, all waiting for their own lock - all the while, the frontend of your store is likely down/non-responsive.

Your screenshot, with included error, is not a ubiquitous error code that refers to any single issue - its a random number, for a random file in your `var/report` directory, it doesn't correlate to anything in the public domain.

In order to see what the random code actually represents, you need to look at the file, with the same name, in the aforementioned directory. If you're new to Magento, then look no further than here, [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

#### Few tips

Just to correct some other answers here,

1. Don't restart a service because something isn't working. Restarting MySQL should **NEVER** be done, doing so flushes caches, drops the "hot" data and will certainly put your server in a much more vulnerable position to recover from. There is no reason MySQL should be restarted in order to diagnose a fault. Instead, you could execute `mysql -e 'show processlist'` and it will give you a list of queries with their process ID. You could then kill the queries (assuming you are confident it is safe to do so and will not cause data loss/corruption/inconsistencies), using `mysql -e 'kill xxx'` (where xxx is the PID).
2. Don't blindly empty your cache. Again, this is the same as above. You don't need to annihilate your store's cache in order to diagnose an issue. Only if you identify the cache as the issue (unlikely), should it then be removed.

NB. Welcome to SE, best of luck debugging.

Comment: Good advice! And in stock CE 1.6.2.0, as downloaded off the site, Magento's DB backup was just outright broken. I killed it when the output file grew to 350MB, revised my backup plan to never use it again. Not sure how large it would have grown. Snorted at the "Stable Version" claim, but it's about par for Magento. Newer versions foul up file permissions under certain conditions, leading to 500 errors and a crashed website.

Comment: This advice helped me to get in my locked up admin after I was deleting a website from a multisite and left the "backup site" setting to yes. I was unable to log in. The var/reports file showed there was a DB query going on. While my login was hanging I could see both that query and an older one. Killing the old query unlocked everything.

Answer (score 0):

Please clean your magento cache by deleting everything inside /var/cache folder. Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me try this right away, I'll get back to you.

Comment: I have done as you suggested, but this rendered the front end inaccessible too :P

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same thing happen to me before as well with a faulty extension.

Go to var/report and look for the report file named with the displayed log-ID

or read this: [There has been an error processing your request - Magenting](http://kb.magenting.com/content/21/37/en/magento-there-has-been-an-error-processing-your-request.html)

In my case it was "ves-brand", an extension that, when I added a brand, crashed Magento.

**Edit:** This was the post that fixed my problem: [Magento: There has been an error processing your request - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570322/magento-there-has-been-an-error-processing-your-request)

Creating the "tmp" folder showed me the actual problem instead of random code.